# How to give an order for HTTP-POST request?

Tags: php, xml, http-post

Hy !

**Case :** 
I wrote an API (in PHP) who received HTTP POST request in xml to update/read or delete some data in another xml file (use to store all data, my client doesn't want SQL or another thing).

But for my test with Simple Rest Client, I just sent request one by one and everything worked fine !

After a short period my client came back because if we do send at the same time more than one request it makes an error : Only one process by text file..

For that my boss maked a "lock" system (create a file who last 1min), 
and now our error is resolved !

But after that, we have another problem ... the first request is fine, but all the request come next are not in the right order.

**Questions :**

- How to try to simulate multiple request post ?

(for now I simply open 2 or 3 window and click on each to send it quickly)

- How to give an order for HTTP-POST request ?

*It's my first question here, and I'm also not good to write in english so please be indulgent and thanks for your time.*

Comment: Hi and welcome. What have you tried? Care to provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Take a look at [the npm loadtest package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loadtest) or [Apache ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to JoErNanO, I create a mcve and find my answers by myself.

For that I write this :

```
// Detect if we got a file "lock"
$nb_file_lock = 0;
if($folder = opendir($GLOBALS['chemin']."XML")){
    while(false !== ($file = readdir($folder))){
        if($file != '.' && $file != '..' && $file != 'datas.xml'){
            $nb_file_lock++;
        }
    } 
    closedir($folder);
}

// If it's not the first request
if($nb_file_lock > 0){
    // Recup the last lock file
    for($i=0;$i<30;$i++){
        if(file_exists($GLOBALS['chemin']."XML/lock_".$i)){
            $lockFile_before=$GLOBALS['chemin']."XML/lock_".$i;
            $last_lock_id=$i;
        }
    }
    // Create file "lock" +1
    $lockFile=$GLOBALS['chemin']."XML/lock_".($last_lock_id+1);
    $fp = fopen($lockFile, 'x');
    fclose($fp);
    // While "lock" exist : sleep
    while(file_exists($lockFile_before)){
        sleep(2);
    }
}else{
    // If not, create the first "lock" file
    $lockFile=$GLOBALS['chemin']."XML/lock_0";
    $fp = fopen($lockFile, 'x');
    fclose($fp);    
}
```